Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd not found error
Am using report view in webforms application using .net framework 4.8. When I run SSRS report getting following error.
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms - 150.1652.0

Error:

Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd:1         
        
        GET http://localhost:56032/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=ewkkde45qukw2o45xjznkt55&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=b13c6f4bddf248a1bc58b86b21d17097&RSProxy=http%3a%2f%2fmy-report.com%2fReportServer&OpType=ReportImage&ResourceStreamID=Blank.gif%20ALT= 404 (Not Found)

Please help to fix this issue.
Below is how my code looks like,
Default.aspx
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
    namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" Height="100%"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>

Default.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
        serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials("sssss", "11111");
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://my-server.com/ReportServer");
        serverReport.ReportPath = "/user/test/report";
    }
}

Web.config
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>        
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
        </handlers>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-16.0.0.0" newVersion="16.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>

Installed latest version report viewer controller. Tried changing web.conf handler settings
